# How to determine if development tools are installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, file-association, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012

We're going through an exercise to identify computers that have Visual Studio installed.

The challenge thus far, is that components of visual studio are installed w/ a lot of other products. SQL Server Client Tools, for example, installs visual studio command line. Our current scan detects this as "Visual Studio".

Do any of you know how to detect the actual Visual Studio files that are used to run the IDE? That which would allow someone to open up Visual Studio and write code?

Comment: "detect it" how?  Why not just look for `devenv.exe` (to file used to run the VS IDE)?

Comment: Detect by version # perhaps? I'm unsure. Currently we get name and version number in our reporting. I'll be happy to look for devenv.exe - is that used in versions from 2005-2010?

Comment: Also, if I understand correctly, BIDS calls devenv.exe to run, but that's not the visual studio IDE that one can write a visual studio application with. Is this correct, do they both use devenv.exe and if so is there a way to differentiate?

Comment: Devenv is the application that visual studio development uses, but bids uses it as well since it is a feature in Visual Studio...

Comment: So the presence of that file could indicate Visual Studio (not ok) or BIDS (which is OK). I'll do some more research to see if there is perhaps a version # difference between the one used w/ VS vs. the one used w/ BIDS. Are there any other files one might find only w/ Visual Studio IDE and not w/ BIDS?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet, is probably to enumerate the registry MSI installers.

Located at:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products`

For example,

I can see, for example:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\0458E21399705D540AE2FD8BCF9AC3AC`

ProductName key is  SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 BI Development Studio